# DateTimeFormatter and DateTimeFormatterBuilder cost

Tags: jodatime

I am building an application which will show dates and times in different formats depending on  the dates themselves and a number of user preferences.  The end result is that there are a large number of potential formats.

These formats are relatively easy to build programatically at runtime, but is there any significant cost to building a new `DateTimeFormatter` using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` each time a date is required to be displayed as opposed to creating a number of static `DateTimeFormatter`s and referencing them?

Comment: If you're processing 100,000 dates per second maybe it has. If you're displaying a form with data queried from a database maybe it doesn't matter...

Comment: Sorry but is that a generic response or based on knowledge of the classes I mentioned?  I get that generally speaking it's fine to do this but I'm specifically interested in finding out if `DateTimeFormatter` has any heavy creation-time costs or if there is another reason why I shouldn't create them on the fly.

Comment: Specific just from source code, construction time is negligible (for that objects) even if it involves many classes (but you may/should profile if it meets your requirements). In general (even if it was pretty heavy) I'd consider that a micro-optimization if you're not sure it's a measured bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTimeFormatter` is immutable and thread-safe, so it is perfectly reasonable for you to cache instances or store them in static variables. The creation process is not especially expensive, but as with all object allocation, it can become expensive in a tight loop.